# Object (Sprite) in 2D java game moves abnormally

Tags: java, eclipse, object

My sprite in my test game flies off screen at super high rates when pressing the key inputs I have and I don't know why.

KeyInput.java:

```
package com.cosmicluck.miner.framework;

import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import com.cosmicluck.miner.window.Handler;

public class KeyInput extends KeyAdapter
{
    Handler handler;

    public KeyInput(Handler handler)
    {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        for(int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++)
        {
            GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

            if(tempObject.getId() == ObjectId.Player)
            {
                if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D) tempObject.setVelX(5);
                if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A) tempObject.setVelX(-5);
            }
        }

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
        {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        for(int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++)
        {
            GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

            if(tempObject.getId() == ObjectId.Player)
            {
                if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D) tempObject.setVelX(0);
                if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A) tempObject.setVelX(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Changing the velocity to anything but `0` for `keyPressed` make the object fly off screen.

And here is my Player.java:

```
package com.cosmicluck.miner.objects;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import com.cosmicluc.miner.framework.GameObject;
import com.cosmicluc.miner.framework.ObjectId;

public class Player extends GameObject
{

private float width = 48, height = 96;

private float gravity = 0.5f;
private final float MAX_SPEED = 10;

public Player(float x, float y, ObjectId id) {
    super(x, y, id);
}

public void tick(LinkedList<GameObject> object) {

    x += velX;
    y += velY;
    if(falling || jumping)
    {
        velY += gravity;

        if(velY > MAX_SPEED)
            velY = MAX_SPEED;
    }
}

public void render(Graphics g) 
{
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect((int)x, (int)y, (int)width, (int)height);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2d.draw(getBounds());
    g2d.draw(getBoundsRight());
    g2d.draw(getBoundsLeft());
    g2d.draw(getBoundsTop());
}

public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return new Rectangle((int) ((int)x+(width/2)-((width/2)/2)), (int) ((int)y+(height/2)), (int)width/2, (int)height/2);
}
public Rectangle getBoundsTop() {
    return new Rectangle((int) ((int)x+(width/2)-((width/2)/2)), (int)y, (int)width/2, (int)height/2);
}
public Rectangle getBoundsRight() {
    return new Rectangle((int) ((int)x+width-5), (int)y+5, (int)5, (int)height-10);
}
public Rectangle getBoundsLeft() {
    return new Rectangle((int)x, (int)y+5, (int)5, (int)height-10);
}
```

}

GameObject.java:

```
package com.cosmicluck.miner.framework;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public abstract class GameObject 
{

protected float x, y;
protected ObjectId id;
protected float velX = 0, velY = 0;
protected boolean falling = true;
protected boolean jumping = false;

public GameObject(float x, float y, ObjectId id)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.id = id;
}

public abstract void tick(LinkedList<GameObject> object);
public abstract void render(Graphics g);
public abstract Rectangle getBounds();

public float getX()
{
    return x;
}
public float getY()
{
    return y;
}
public void setX(float x)
{
    this.x = x;
}
public void setY(float y)
{
    this.y = y;
}

public float getVelX()
{
    return velX;
}
public float getVelY()
{
    return velY;
}
public void setVelX(float velX)
{
    this.velX = x;
}
public void setVelY(float velY)
{
    this.velY = y;
}

public boolean isFalling() {
    return falling;
}

public void setFalling(boolean falling) {
    this.falling = falling;
}

public boolean isJumping() {
    return jumping;
}

public void setJumping(boolean jumping) {
    this.jumping = jumping;
}

public ObjectId getId()
{
    return id;
}
```

}

Game.java:

```
package com.cosmicluck.miner.window;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.util.Random;

import com.cosmicluc.miner.framework.KeyInput;
import com.cosmicluc.miner.framework.ObjectId;
import com.cosmicluc.miner.objects.Player;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = -905290418752159869L;

private boolean running = false;
private Thread thread;

public static int WIDTH, HEIGHT;

//Object
Handler handler;

Random rand = new Random();

private void init()
{
    WIDTH = getWidth();
    HEIGHT = getHeight();
    handler = new Handler();

    handler.addObject(new Player(100, 100, handler, ObjectId.Player));

    handler.createLevel();

    this.addKeyListener(new KeyInput(handler));
}

public synchronized void start(){
    if(running)
        return;

    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

public void run()
{
    init();
    this.requestFocus();
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
    double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
    double delta = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int updates = 0;
    int frames = 0;
    while(running){
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
        while(delta >= 1){
            tick();
            updates++;
            delta--;
        }
        render();
        frames++;

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
            timer += 1000;
            System.out.println("FPS: " + frames + " TICKS: " + updates);
            frames = 0;
            updates = 0;
        }
    }
}

private void tick()
{
    handler.tick();
}
private void render()
{
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null)
    {
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    ////////////////////////////////////
    //Draw here
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    handler.render(g);

    ////////////////////////////////////
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    new Window(800, 600, "Miner Madness - Prototype", new Game());
}
```

}

Thank you ahead of time!

EDIT: FIXED!
I had a silly error in my GameObject when I was making velX/velY = x,y respectively. Thank you all for you help! :)

Comment: Where is the code that calls the tick method? And why does the tick method have the parameter `LinkedList<GameObject> object`?

Comment: Where's the code that animates this Is it in `GameObject` ? Is the returned object from `GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);` always the same reference?

Comment: @hoyah_hayoh The tick method is called in my main Game.java class, and by having the LinkedList it calls for every game object all at once. And rind bearer, I have just added the GameObject code in my post.

Comment: can you include the code for where the tick method is called, as it is maybe a problem with the update speed of that - how many times per second is the method supposed to be called? Maybe check how many times it is actually being called.

Comment: ok... and where is THAT method being called?

Comment: Its being called in Game.java

Comment: My money is on a lack of a proper delay at the end of your animation loop. Some kind of `Thread.sleep` between frames.

Comment: @Michael Eric Oberlin Thats also what im thinking

Comment: Show the code that actually calls all of these tick methods!!!!!

Comment: Added the whole game.java class, and I think I do need a Thread.sleep but I don't know where to put it.

Comment: At its current state the question looks like off-topic. I recommend you to edit it according to [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): at least, to remove all the code, not related to the problem, and to edit tags. Please understand that I'm not saying it out of tediousness. Just concerned about the time of people who would come to seek an answer about animation in Java, but find a lesson about writing setters. :)

Comment: Also, tags [tag:eclipse] and [tag:object] don't seem to be good for this question. The problem is not in the eclipse workflow. And the object is an ambigous tag itself. IMHO, [tag:java] is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should assign the method parameters to fields, not other fields.

```
public void setVelX(float velX)
{
    this.velX = velX;
}
public void setVelY(float velY)
{
    this.velY = velY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setVelX(float velX)
{
    this.velX = x;
}
public void setVelY(float velY)
{
    this.velY = y;
}
```

Your setters in GameObject are incorrect.

Comment: How would you fix them? I don't see the problem